# Entering new date in a column does not autoformat

Tags: google-sheets

I've already done `Format > Number > More Formats > More Date and Time formats` for the entire column but the new date entries are still not auto formatted, how can I make it auto format?

Here's the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 sure, it's shared in post and is editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select **A7** cell
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`C`</kbd>**
- select **A8** cell or **A8:A** range
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`V`</kbd>**

[image: 0]

- to make it automatic after you pre-format the range you need to input hours too like:

  ```
  2/2 8:00
  ```




  ```
  5/28 0:00
  ```


  etc.

Comment: But how do I make it so it auto formats it like excel? I'd have to do this each time if datetime is entered manually? I believe we can do it automatically with onEdit, but prefer not to go there.

Comment: @sojim2 answer updated